Hover color override for Mantine (v7) Button not working
I have this simple button using React and Mantine for testing an issue I have (v7.13.3)
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { MantineProvider, Button } from "@mantine/core";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <MantineProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Button
        size="md"
        styles={{
          root: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
          },
        }}
      >
        TEST BUTTON
      </Button>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </MantineProvider>
);

But hovering the button doesn't actually change the color as expected. Hovering does change the color when not actually overriding it though. I've seen similar examples using earlier versions of Mantine and they worked just fine.
I expected a blue button to show with the Text "TEST BUTTON" which then turned red once hovered over.

Try sx prop emotion.
`    <Button
        size="md"
        sx={(theme) => ({
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
        })}
      >
        TEST BUTTON
      </Button>`

https://mantine.dev/styles/emotion/
